# Text query matching (tricky)

Tags: java, regex, string, match

I went for a microsoft coding challenge at college and this was the question asked:

> Write a program that takes two strings as input, one is a query, and the other is a string that may or may not contain that query. Your program needs to find if the query is contained within the body string.
>
> 1) The query should only match the body text if it matches the start of a word within the body text.
>
> 2) That is, the beginning of the query must also be the start of a word within the body text. For example, the query "cat" would match the strings "cat", "cat toy", "this is a cat", and "catty". However, the query "cat" would not match the string "location".
>
> 3) Your program should  be case insensitive.
>
> 4) Your program needs to be able to match queries without spaces in them, even if the body does have spaces. For example, the string "Luke Johnston" would be matched by the query "luke j" and the query "lukej".
>
> 5) However, this does not work the other way around. The query "luke j" should not match the string "lukejohnston".

I am able to write a code that satisfies the first 4 requirements but I am unable to find a solution for the 5th one. Any hint/help is appreciated. Here is my version of the code.

```
package regex;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextQueryMatch {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the Text: ");
    String text = in.nextLine();
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    String[] substexts = text.split("\\s");
    text = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < substexts.length; i++){
        char capLetter = Character.toUpperCase(substexts[i].charAt(0));
        text += capLetter + substexts[i].substring(1, substexts[i].length());
    }
    System.out.println(text);
    System.out.print("Enter the Query: ");
    String query = in.nextLine();
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    String[] subquerys = query.split("\\s");
    query = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < subquerys.length; i++){
        char capLetter = Character.toUpperCase(subquerys[i].charAt(0));
        query += capLetter + subquerys[i].substring(1, subquerys[i].length());
    }
    System.out.println(query);
    System.out.print("Match: ");
    if(text.matches("(.*)"+query.charAt(0)+"(.*)")){
        text=text.toLowerCase();
        query=query.toLowerCase();
        System.out.print(text.matches("(.*)"+query+"(.*)"));
    }else{
        System.out.print("False");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a converting the query into a regular expression would suffice for all the given conditions.

According to the question,

By points 1 & 2, the query should match the text only if the query-string is in the beginning of the text or succeeds a space. So basically the regular expression for this would be something like -

```
(^|\s)(query-string)
```

Point 3 needs the query to be case-insensitive, which can be handled when the query-regex is compiled.

For points 4 & 5- the query should match the text even if the query does not have a space, but if a space exists in the query, it should be properly matched in the text.

So, we need to transform our regex in such a way, that after every character(or space), the regex can handle spaces which may or may not be present.In that way, we assume that the character(or space) must be matched while the space after it is conditional.

This should work -

```
 public static boolean find_match(String query, String text){
    String regex = "(?:^|\\s)(" + query.replaceAll(".(?!$)", "$0(?:\\\\s*)") + ")";
    //System.out.println("Regex -> " + regex);
    Pattern re = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);    
    return re.matcher(text).find();
 }
```

Testing this function -

```
public static void main(String []args){        
    String query1 = "cat";
    String[] text1 = {
        "Cat",
        "caT toy",
        "This is a CaT",
        "caTty",
        "loCation"
    };
    for(String s : text1){
        System.out.println("Query -> " + query1 + "\nText -> " + s + "\n" + find_match(query1, s) + "\n");
    }
    String query2 = "luke j";
    String query3 = "lukej";
    String[] text2 = {
        "Luke Johnson",
        "lukejohnson",
        "Luke      Johson",
        "This is Luke  Johnson",
        "L ukeJohnson",
        "L uke Johnson"
    };
    for(String s : text2){
        System.out.println("Query -> " + query2 + "\nText -> " + s + "\n" + find_match(query2, s));
        System.out.println("Query -> " + query3 + "\nText -> " + s + "\n" + find_match(query3, s) + "\n");
    }    
 }
```

The Output ->

```
Query -> cat
Text -> Cat
true

Query -> cat
Text -> caT toy
true

Query -> cat
Text -> This is a CaT
true

Query -> cat
Text -> caTty
true

Query -> cat
Text -> loCation
false

Query -> luke j
Text -> Luke Johnson
true
Query -> lukej
Text -> Luke Johnson
true

Query -> luke j
Text -> lukejohnson
false
Query -> lukej
Text -> lukejohnson
true

Query -> luke j
Text -> Luke      Johson
true
Query -> lukej
Text -> Luke      Johson
true

Query -> luke j
Text -> This is Luke  Johnson
true
Query -> lukej
Text -> This is Luke  Johnson
true

Query -> luke j
Text -> L ukeJohnson
false
Query -> lukej
Text -> L ukeJohnson
true

Query -> luke j
Text -> L uke Johnson
true
Query -> lukej
Text -> L uke Johnson
true
```

Hopefully, this helped-

Comment: It helped. Could you please elaborate with the regex statement. For query="luke j" it gives regex=(?:^|\s)(l(?:\s*)u(?:\s*)k(?:\s*)e(?:\s*) (?:\s*)j). I am new to using regex and was referring [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) and couldn't find a few symbols.

Comment: Grouping symbols , () and (?:) are capturing and non-capturing groups. Refer them [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).  For the rest of the symbols, use [this](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)

Comment: [This](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) tutorial is pretty comprehensive, if you want to begin regex properly from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method:

```
public static boolean match(String text, String query) {
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    query = query.toLowerCase();

    String noSpaces = text.replaceAll(" ", "");
    String[] tWords = text.split(" ");

    if (text.startsWith(query) || noSpaces.startsWith(query)) {
        return true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tWords.length; i++) {
        if (tWords[i].startsWith(query)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution but would fail if I pass text="A Luke Johnston" and query="luke j", because in the for loop, it will fail for i=2 as it will be comparing johnston with luke j.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of possible cases to determine whether your QUERY in contained in the BODY. Let's take the explain of the CAT and the other sample body string you gave in the question.

Your Query will have the following version:-
<*cat*> : Case when the cat in between the sentence
<_cat>  : Case when the sentence ends with cat or followed by , or . or any symbol (you might wanna check the succeeding charactor using ASCII )
  : When sentence starts with cat.
   : Body is single word sentence cat you can use SIZE function to confirm.
_ is referred to as SPACE

Firstly, you need to convert the entire body and the query string into LOWERCASE or UPPERCASE (Or not because it is not specified the question whether the matching operation is case sensitive or not)